# Resolve function not found errors on created DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with JS and I'm a bit confused on something. When a user clicks an element I'd like to create an image element and animate it.

```
element = document.createElement("IMG");
element.src = "/path/to/file.jpg";
element.addClass("class1");
```

I receive the following error:

> element.addClass is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing DOM methods with jQuery methods. `addClass` is a jQuery method, but `element` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

If you want to stick to jQuery, the code would be:

```
var element = $("<img>", {
    src: "/path/to/file.jpg",
    "class": "class1"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in DOM we have something like classList:

```
element.classList.add("className");
```

addClass() method in in Jquery.